# WPF RichTextBox autoscroll not works when add Document.Blocks in Background worker

Tags: wpf, vb.net, richtextbox, autoscroll

I use WPF rich text box to log data process:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbLog" IsReadOnly="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code-behind I use BackgroundWorker to process data and update log by ProgressChanged event handler:

```
Private Sub WorkerReport(sender as Object, e as ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles Worker.ProgressChanged
  Dim para as New Paragraph
  para.Inlines.Add(New Run(...some data))
  rtbLog.Document.Blocks.Add(para)
  rtbLog.ScrollToEnd()
End Sub
```

New data is appends successfully, but RichTextBox don't scrolls to end.

What is the problem, why my solution is not working?

Thank you for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

I've understood my mistake.
While RichTextBox is wrapped by ScrollViewer, it is not scroll by ScrollToEnd().
After I deleted ScrollViewer, it's works normally.